# How do you defeat the yeti zombie?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I play the first plant vs zombies game and I am on the level with the yeti zombie. There is just 1 problem. It has to much health and it keeps running away. Does anyone have a tip on defeating the yeti? It looks like it has around the health of a buckethead zombie. How fast does it go when running away?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instant kill plants like the Squash, Jalapeno and cherry Bomb can kill him easily. His HP is only 1350 so he should not be that hard to kill with the right plants (Seeing a standard Buckethead has 1300). And if he runs away he still acts like a zombie would, but in a different direction so placing plants there (like a Tallnut) should block him from fleeing.